# NiceScrollbar with Pageslide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add [jQuery Nice Scrollbar](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) to slide panel which used [jQuery Page Slide plugin](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/).

But it doesn't seems work. Please kindly help me check my code, here's the example page

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69217301/scroll/index.html

Am i giving wrong id or is it because of something missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#pageslide 
  {
    background-color: #333333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #222222 inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
   padding: 20px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 260px;
}
```